# SQL - Do all SELECT variables written as functions need to be referenced in GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, select, group-by

-- Would this still run correctly without all 3 `GROUP BY` variables included? E.g., if clause was only `GROUP BY start_station_name`?

```sql
SELECT 
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name,
  end_station_name,
  usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

Comment: If start_station_name is the primary key, or only column in a unique constraint, it can work (depending on dbms.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not run correctly. The column(s) should be aggregated or part of the group by statement.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jarlh mentions in his comment, some DBMS implement the SQL99 version of GROUP BY where it is not necessary to group by columns that are functionally dependent of those in the group by clause. This is for example valid in postgres 15:

```
create table t 
( x int not null primary key
, y int not null
, z int not null);

select x, y, count(z)
from t
group by x;
```

but not in Oracle 21c since it implements the earlier SQL92 definition, where all columns need to be part of the group by.

It is also worth noting that you may get confusing result if you group by individual columns, and apply functions in the select part. This is valid, but is probably not the intention:

```
with t(n) as ( 
    values (4),(-4)
)
select abs(n), count(1) 
from t 
group by n

4   1
4   1
```

Compared with:

```
with t(n) as ( 
    values (4),(-4)
)
select abs(n), count(1) 
from t 
group by abs(n)

4   2
```